# Remove entire row of np array if there is duplicate in first column

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have the following test array:

`arr = np.array([[1, 2, 3], [1,3,7], [2,1,3], [4, 5, 6], [1,4,7], [2,7,6])`

I need to remove every row that has a duplicate value in the first column (but still keeping the first instance of that value). For this test array I require the following output:

`result=[1,2,3],[2,1,3],[4,5,6]`

So the first row where 1 is in the first column is kept, and the first row where 2 is in the column is kept etc...

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`return_index` in `np.unique` is quite useful for this:

```
_, i = np.unique(arr[:,0], return_index=True)

arr[i]
array([[1, 2, 3],
       [2, 1, 3],
       [4, 5, 6]])
```

Comment: Thanks! I was trying to use np.unique but didn't know how to get it to specify just one column.

What does the _, bit mean?

Comment: That is convention variable name for something that you don't need @okvoyce Like the unique values here, first returned value, which is not needed